# Get IP of visitor from google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ip, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

How can I get the IP of the visitor in my google analytics account? 
The API of GA https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/ provide many information about the location of the visitor such as city, country, etc.. all of them all derived by the IP, However I didn't find the way to get the IP.

Note : I am using the v3 API of GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GA does not expose the visitors IP anywhere (also in some jurisdictions - e.g. all of the European Union - IP is considered personally identifiable information and would not allowed to be stored unless anonymized by cutting of a part of it, which would probably defy your purpose). Generally, if things are not in the list of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) (and the [BigQuery export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) for GA Premium accounts) then they are not available